# initialized keycloak instance unable to automatically authenticate in PKCE

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, pkce, keycloak-js

I have a react application that using keycloak for some protected routes. I am creating a new keycloak instance with the following json :

```json
{
  "realm": "demo",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "javascript-app",
  "public-client": true,
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

The init method is defined as follows to enable PKCE :

```js
export function initKeycloak() {
  _kc.init({
    onLoad: "check-sso",
    pkceMethod: "S256",
    silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
      window.location.origin + "/silent-check-sso.html",
  });
}
```

The problem is when the keycloak instance created it is not authenticating automatically in scenarios like refreshing the page. Thoese requests are returning with error message like :

`http://localhost:3000/keycloak/login#error=invalid_request&error_description=Missing+parameter%3A+code_challenge_method&state=4ebff627-22af-4d25-864a-9e90ccd089f7`

I tried adding the following in the json file:

```json
  "on-load": "check-sso",
  "code-challenge-method": "S256",
  "pkce-method": "S256",
```

But they are not working.

Is there a way to eliminate this error while keycloak instance is created ? or to invoke keycloak.init() automatically before keyclaok turns to initialized state ?